# GuzzlePHP Request Query String

Tags: php, guzzle, amazon-clouddrive

I'm working on an application using Amazon's CloudDrive SDK. When requesting a list of folders or files, you can send filters in the query string, but the values of each filter needs to have special characters escaped (included spaces, much like a Linux command line argument). I'm not entirely sure how to send the string through Guzzle (or PHP in general) so that its interpreted by the API as escaped strings.

If I use 'addcslashes' and define all the characters necessary, the API returns with `Invalid filter:name:Test\`, but if I simply cURL the same endpoint, it returns the proper data.

When using `addcslashes` in PHP, the request value ends up being "name:Test\ Folder AND kind:FOLDER". But as I said, this fails up at the endpoint.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I posted this question after a day or so of messing around with the issue with no resolution and immediately after posting, I tried another method that seemed to solve my issue...

In the Guzzle library ,setting the Encoding type of the request to `RFC1738` seemed to fix the issue and return the proper data. Although, I still needed to call `addcslashes` on the value.